# I have a string , in that I want to search the parentheses pair with proper nested and it must have some value inside it in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string , in that I want to search the parentheses pair with proper nested and it must have some value inside it in javascript.
for example,

```
String = "@PriceMovement@-(@AssetProof@-(@TradeImpact@)/45)-@UninvestedCashImpact@"
```

In the above string all the variables are covered with **@** symbol.
As per the above statement `TradeImpact` will be divided by 45 first and remaining calculation has been made, if the user will enter like below then I should show error that wrong parentheses used(I cant do this with the count of opening and closing braces as the below string will also having equal start and close braces). Please help me to validate it thanks in advance.

```
String = "@PriceMovement@-(@AssetProof@-(@TradeImpact@))/45)-((@UninvestedCashImpact@)"
```

Comment: What do you exactly want ? Check that the string is valid according to your pattern?

Comment: I suppose to validate the given string that has properly nested

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to replace variables with values and apply `eval` to the resulting string:

```
str = "@PriceMovement@-(@AssetProof@-(@TradeImpact@))/45)-((@UninvestedCashImpact@)"
values = {
    PriceMovement: 1,
    AssetProof: 2,
    TradeImpact: 3, 
    UninvestedCashImpact: 5
}

try {
    str = str.replace(/@(\w+)@/g, function($0, $1) {
        return values[$1]
    })
    result = eval(str)
    alert(result)
} catch(e) {
    alert("Error: " + e)
}
```

This also catches other types of syntax errors, like invalid operators.

To check just brackets' nesting, replace `(...)` in a loop until there are no more matches. Then, check if the string contains an unpaired opening or closing bracket:

```
re = /\([^()]*\)/g
while(str.match(re))
    str = str.replace(re, '')
if(str.match(/[()]/))
    alert("INVALID NESTING")
```

Comment: If the user will enter ((())) , then this will treated as valid, but it should not . Actually I need a reg epression that will validate that the brackets are properly nested and it conatains only +/*-()@ symbols in it , Please help me to find out

Comment: @user2181727: try replacing `[^()]*` with `[allowed-chars]+`.